# Executing Code in a String with Pipeline and Arguments

Tags: powershell

I am working on a project in PowerShell that requires executing arbitrary code received as a string, handling pipeline input, and parsing arguments. Here is the code needed to simulated the environment:

```
$SBText = @'
begin {
    foreach ($arg in $args) {
        Write-Host "arg={$arg}"
    }
}
process {
    Write-Host "[$Input]"
}
'@
$ArgText = '"This is a" test "of the arguments"'
$PipedItems = 'Pipe#1', 'Pipe#2'
```

Goals:

1. Execute the arbitrary code in $SBText.
2. Accepts Pipeline input.
3. Parse arguments from $ArgText.
4. Preferably execute the above in a single line.
5. Preferably avoid creating additional variables.

Desired Output:

```
arg={This is a}
arg={test}
arg={of the arguments}
[Pipe#1]
[Pipe#2]
```

I prefer the simplicity of the `-ArgumentList` option in the `Invoke-Command` method. However, I had to surround $SBText within dot sourcing code to support multiple clauses:

```
$PipedItems | Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create('$Input | . {' + $SBText + '} @args')) -ArgumentList ($ArgText | select-string '(?:"[^"]*"|\S)+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value.Trim('"')
```

I prefer the simplicity of executing code that dot sourcing provides. However, it seems the only way to splat an array is to first save it in a variable:

```
$MyArgs = ($ArgText | select-string '(?:"[^"]*"|\S)+' -AllMatches).Matches.Value.Trim('"'); $PipedItems | . ([ScriptBlock]::Create($SBText)) @MyArgs
```

Can an array be splatted without first saving it to a variable?  Or is there an entirely different alternative approach?

Comment: from the start this seem like prone to failure. specially the way you're looking to pass in arguments

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, the arguments are originally passed to a CMD file, command line arguments saved to an environment variable, and then parsed in PowerShell.  I'm open to an alternative approach.

Comment: I don't have an alternative approach, I wouldn't consider doing this in the first place or mixing powershell with batch but for sure someone will help you find a better way. regarding the question, no, splatting only works with a variable. what you could do instead could be passing the args as a simple string and doing the parsing inside the function. then you wouldn't require splatting in the first place

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, thank you for taking a look at the question, and for the comment.  It's useful to know what can and can't be done.